# FlowType React Context

Tags: flowtype

Is there a way to make React [Context](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/context.html) type-safe with flow type?

For example :

```
Button.contextTypes = {
  color: React.PropTypes.string
};
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Unfortunately, it is inherently not possible because `Context` is not known at compile time ([so I was told](https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/2916#issuecomment-263523543)).

Comment: Note that this is about the legacy context API, not the production one: https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/2916#issuecomment-440378951

Answer (score 0):

A bit of a workaround I use is pulling the the context from the consumer at the parent level, and then calling proptypes at the child...

Parent

```
//parent
class Parent extends component {
render(){
return (
    <Consumer>{(context)=>{
       const { color } = context
       return(
          <div>
             <Button color={color} />
          </div>
        )}}</Consumer>
}
```

Child

```
//Button 
... 
Button.contextTypes = {
  color: React.PropTypes.string
};
...
```